# Sum of Skellam-distributed number of random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i$ are i.i.d, and $N \sim \text{Skellam}(\mu_1$, $\mu_2$). Is it possible to find a closed form for the p.d.f of $S_N$, defined by $S_N = X_1 + \cdots X_N$ when $N \ge 0$, and $S_{-N} = -S_N$, in the case where 1. $X_i \sim \text{Normal}(m,\sigma^2)$ and 2. $X_i \sim \text{Uniform}(a,b)$

Stated alternatively, suppose $N_1 \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_1)$ and $N_2 \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_2)$. What is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} X_i - \sum_{i=1}^{N_2} X_i$ ?

I know that this is linked to "compound Poisson distributions". I have not been able to find any analytical expressions so far for the difference of two compound Poisson distributions. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about [this Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) which has support over all integers? What is $S_N$ if $N$ is negative?

Comment: Apologies, please see edit